# How to change google service account profile picture in high quality?

Tags: node.js, google-admin-sdk

I am using and it working fine, Problem is that it down scales the image to 96 X 96. If i upload same image from google dashboard, it makes the image crop then saves in good quality.

```
service.users.photos.update(
      {
        userKey: req.user.email,
        auth: jwtClient,
        requestBody: {
          photoData: newfile,
          width: '800',
          height: '800',
          kind: 'admin#directory#user#photo'
        }
      },
      (err, response) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Are you using the `users.photos.update()` endpoint?

Comment: Yes. Mentioned the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This is working as intended.*

#### More Information:

According to the Directory API documentation for `Users.photos: update`:

> Whatever the size of the photo being uploaded, the API downsizes it to 96x96 pixels.

So this is as expected.

#### References:

- [Method: users.photos.update | Directory API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/update)